# Finding all quads in a mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh

I'm loading a mesh via Three.js, and I'm trying to texture each quad individually. Right now I can texture each face (tri), but I'm not sure how to determine if the current and last triangle are part of a quad (they'll share two vertices, but which ones?)

How can I figure out if two triangles form a quad?

```
var last = null;
for(var i in geometry.faces)
{
    var face = geometry.faces[i];
    var normal = face.normal.clone().normalize();

    if(normal.y >= 0.9999)
    {
        face.materialIndex = 1;

        //Determine if face & last are part of a quad
        if(face && last == same quad)
        {
            face.color = last.color;
        }
        else
        {
            face.color = new THREE.Color(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF); 
        }

        last = face;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to realize that the problem is under-defined. In a connected triangle mesh, every triangle has 3 neighbors. Each one of them could be it's quad. So you can only make a good guess as to what are quads. Your choice of checking the normal is a good start, but would not work for example if the mesh was a plane.

The first step is to find all the neighbors for each triangle. Each triangle has exactly 3 neighbors. This is a fun two pass algorithm that should be linear in time and memory. Each triangle should have something like neighbors[3] - which are indices to other triangles.

Then you can compute a "quadiness" heuristic for each of them. They should be roughly coplanar and rectangular. I would score by normals and inner angles on the four sides. Once you have those, you can sort all triangles by this number. Remove the best guesses first, merge them into a quad, and keep going until you are done.

This should work pretty ok most of the time, but there will be cases where this breaks down. Depending on why you need quads you can try to fix your heuristic function to fit your case. But it is important to remember that there is no right solution. The problem is under defined.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right that it's a user defined problem. I may need to rethink how I'm trying to do this, for more flexibility if nothing else.

Comment: Btw, I just remembered that some 3d packages do export this information as something called "smoothing groups". Triangles with the same group id are one original polygon. I don't know if three.js exposes this though.